# Ajax call to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having 2 questions 1st : I am trying to run this file but it is not even giving any error not showing result please tell what is the problem
2. I want to get the names in the dropdown as well so i have put select tag but I don't know how to use it to get the list of names...please suggest

My html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>D3</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript></script>
     </head>



    <body>
 <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 
         <select>
          </select> 
            </body>
    </html>

My script.js file

    $("button").click(function() {

    $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
    $ ("ul").append("<li>"+value.name +"</li>");
    });

    });
    });
```

My json file

```
[{
  "name": "obs",
  "date": "1458834026000"
  "attr001": "brs1"
  "attr002": "crs1"
  "attr003": "drs1"
}, {
  "name": "hid",
  "date": "1458774000000"
  "attr001": "ffrs1"
  "attr002": "grrs1"
  "attr003": "mno1"
}, {
  "name": "qwe",
  "date": "1425744000000"
  "attr001": "klm1"
  "attr002": "wer1"
  "attr003": "iop1"
}, {
  "name": "rty",
  "date": "1458774000000"
  "attr001": "yrs1"
  "attr002": "qws1"
  "attr003": "prs1"
}]
```

Comment: I don't see any `<button>` element in the markup

Comment: Please have alook now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It was not giving error because you've forgot to put `"`(closing inverted comma) end of `type/javascript`.

I've tested this one. Its working with your `Json` file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <select>
    </select> 
</body>
</html>
```

Now in your `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            $ ("select").append("<option>"+value.name +"</option>");
        });

    });
})
```

2. You were using `ul` and `li` instead of `option` tag.

**Update** : As you asked in comment.

`script.js`

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(document).on("click","button",function() {
    // alert('hi')
        $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                $ ("#dropdown1").append("<option value="+key+">"+value.name +"</option>");
            });

        });
    });
    $(document).on('change','#dropdown1',function(){
        //do some ajax call and put the data into another dropdown e.g.,
        $.get('data.json',function(obj){
            obj = JSON.parse(obj)
            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                $ ("#dropdown2").append("<option value="+key+">"+value.name +"</option>");
            });
        })
    })
})
```

and in `html`

```
<body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <select id="dropdown1"></select> 
    <select id="dropdown2"></select> 
</body>
```

Comment: Do let me know whether it worked or not. It should be working fine.

Comment: glad i could help. Please mark as accepted answer it will help me earn some reputation also. :P

Comment: Can you just tell me also that i want to include one more dropdown so that when i click on one option from this dropdown the 2nd dropdown should get populated for eg of country state dropdowns dont know how to do with ajax

Comment: yeah sure. give me few mins.

Comment: As you wanted I've updated the answer. do let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for ur fast reply..Actually as now I am getting in one dropdown the list of names so i want when user click on one name the 2nd dropdown shud gets updated by list of attributes values corresponding to that name ...sorry if i confused you

Comment: Let me explain everything.

You have one dropdown
when you click on any option from your first dropdown, you will also have to take some `ids` from your first dropdown so that using that id you'll do any get or post request to url and the url will return specific data using that id.

still not clear ? do let me know.

Comment: Thank you for clearing somehow I  understood ..but how should I get id's from the selected item from the dropdown

Comment: okay. let me explain again with example and send you some code over email or any way you prefer which will help you understand better. give me your email id I'm sending the codes right away.

Comment: larochejasmin1@gmail.com

Comment: you comfortable with php ? or any other language should I write the server code ?

Comment: no in this project using java as backend and my sql as database and html for frontend

Comment: I just mailed you the files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108494/discussion-between-imrealashu-and-siya).

Comment: I removed the second dropdown because there I want to have a list box but I dont know how should I get corresponding values from by clicking on value from 1st dropdown into list box

Comment: As above you can see my json file as now i m getting values in 1sr dropdown as obs, hid I want say if i click on *obs* in list box i want to get brs1,crs1,drs1..please suggest !!! Thank you